# subscribe to array of nested Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have array containing objects each object has two props one of it is a observable value

`let myArray = [{def: 'name1', value: EventEmitter_}, {def: 'name2', value: EventEmitter_}]`

What im trying to do is subscribe to the Observables and and return the root Object where the change occurred

so far I only get the specific value

```
      myArray.forEach(e => {
        e.value.subscribe(e => console.log(e))
      })
```

I tried using `merge`

```
  merge(myArray).subscribe((v)=> {
        console.log(v)
       })
```

but that does not work if the Observable is nested

Comment: you're overriding `e` param. `e.value.subscribe(value => console.log(e, value))`

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the value stream.

```
myArray.forEach(e => {
  e.value.pipe(
    map(v => [e.def, v]),
  ).subscribe(([d, v]) => console.log(`Root ${d} returned %{v}`));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obs = merge(
    ...this.array.map((x: any) =>
      x.value.pipe(map((res) => ({ def: x.def, response: res })))
    )
  );
```

You merge the "observables" transformed with a property "def", and a property "response". So you only need one subscripcion

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m5lgjd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)